# Understanding the time taken by a large database query over AWS intra-region network

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am experimenting to determine the performance of a database query to RDS Postgres instance executed from a Python script running on a EC2 instance. For this experiment, both instances are in the free tier. Both instances are in the same region. Here is the code:

```py
import psycopg2
import time
import random
import string

CHUNK_SIZE = 10000000
N_CHUNKS = 10 # Do in chunks, so as to avoid a huge list and running out of memory

def ms_now():
    return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

class Timer():
    def __init__(self, timestamp_function=ms_now):
        self.timestamp_function = timestamp_function
        self.start = self.timestamp_function()

    def stop(self):
        return self.timestamp_function() - self.start

def random_text():
    result = ''
    for i in range(N_CHUNKS):
        result += ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(CHUNK_SIZE)])
    return result

def connect():
    # Fill out host, port, dbname, username and password here

    return psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        dbname=dbname,
        user=username,
        password=password
    )

def create_database(conn):
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS speed_test;")
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE speed_test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, data text);")
        conn.commit()
        timer = Timer()
        data = random_text()
        print(f"Generation time: {timer.stop()}ms")
        timer = Timer()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO speed_test (data) VALUES (%s);", (data,))
        conn.commit()
        print(f"Insertion time: {timer.stop()}ms")

def query_database(conn):
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        timer = Timer()
        cursor.execute("SELECT data FROM speed_test;")
        print(f"Query time: {timer.stop()}ms")

conn = connect()
create_database(conn)
query_database(conn)
```

The code measures two times:

1. The time of inserting a single row with a single column (besides the id) containing `N_CHUNKS * 10M` characters.
2. The time of querying the database to obtain that row.

In both cases, we measure the client time, which means that it includes the time of the network transfer between the instances.

I have difficulty understanding the results for the different values of `N_CHUNKS`.

The output for `N_CHUNKS = 10` (i.e. 100M characters):

```
Generation time: 53820ms
Insertion time: 13128ms
Query time: 2510ms
```

The output for `N_CHUNKS = 5` (i.e. 50M characters):

```
Generation time: 26505ms
Insertion time: 3867ms
Query time: 543ms
```

While the amount of data being transferred is two times smaller in the second test, which is properly reflected in the generation time, both the insertion and the query time decreased by much more than a factor of two. The data clearly fits in the **RAM** in both tests. So, how can these timing results be explained?